# Prevent interaction with asp.net form while it loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to disallow interaction with an asp.net form during its processing.
In my opinion I should use a javascript event for this but I'm a little bit confused about which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a javascript plugin like [BlockUi](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to place an overlay on the page until all requests have completed and the page is fully initialised.